# How to protect reactjs resources with spring boot based authentiation?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, react-router-dom

My current project state:

- I am working on a Web Application with ReactJs (frontend) and spring boot (backend).
- When I deploy this application, I package react code with my spring boot jar using [gradle-node-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin)

Problem:

- I understand that I should serve all the resources that require authentication from the server. - However, I'm having a hard time understanding if there is a way to put certain components/routes of my react project behind the authentication API.
- An example is Google Docs, where Google does not let you create any new document (or even see the text canvas) without actually logging in.
- Currently only the data I'm loading from the database is protected under spring security, but I have a design tool written in Javascript in my react project, that I'd like to protect as well.
- Is this possible through spring security or should I just assume that everything under my react project can be accessed publicly?
- In other words how do I protect the javascript based UI only page, where you are not making any backend calls to get authentication information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Call Authenticate API when the page loads to see if user's session is authenticated. I think spring security can do this. Based on the response, you can restrict the route.

```
<Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        authenticateApiResponse.authenticated ? (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/profile",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
```

Now user can only go to **profile** screen if he's authenticated by backend API.

Comment: Is it possible for someone to remove the "localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')" from javascript on the browser itself, and then be able to access a path like "/profile" that is another javascript in the react app and not a backend REST api?

Comment: yes. Anyone can delete it via browser console. "localStorage.clear()" or "localStorage.removeItem()" or even from Application window in browser console.

Comment: How does it protect the javascript at path "/profile" (which is not a server a REST call that can be easily protected in spring security) then?

Comment: I've update my answer. Instead of storing anything on UI, you will be calling a backend API to authenticate user. Only if the user is authenticated by backend server, he can go to profile page. It has some missing pieces like how you make the API calls and how you store the data. But this solution might work for you and user's can't manipulate data to goto restricted pages.